# Placing common attributes in the proper class

Tags: java, composition

I have an object A which contains object B as one of it's attribute, which further has object C as one of it's attribute. I also have some attributes which are common to all of these 3 objects.

Where should I place these common attributes so that multiple copies are not created, and suppose if I pass object C to a function then only the properties of object C are exposed. If I place attributes in Class C then to get common attributes, my code will have to depend on object C's getter method. If I place them in class A then some properties which are not required by object C will be visible to it.

Comment: Please show the code of your classes (shorten them to the basics or create a simple but equivalent example that shows your problem).

Comment: "Where should I place these common attributes so that multiple copies are not created" - Do `A`, `B`, `C` have same attributes or they are dependent on an object with some attributes. Because let's suppose `id` is common attribute, then all three objects have to have their own copy of `id` attribute. I get a feeling that your case is of a dependency.

Comment: It depends™ it's hard to figure out a model with such abstract notions as A, B, C

Answer (score 0):

If A, B, C have common properties they can naturally share an Interface with getters for those properties. Once you have such interface, say

```
interface CommonInterface {
 Object getMyProperty()

}
 class B extends CommonInterface {           
    [....]
 }
 class A extends CommonInterface {
    private CommonInterface B myBInstance;  
       [....]
 }
```

At this point you can use the ChainOfResposibility pattern: implementing an abstract class as

```
abstract class CommonProperties implements CommonInterface {
  protected CommonProperties successor;

public void setSuccessor(PurchasePower successor) {
  this.successor = successor;
}

public Object processRequest(YourRequestClass request){
  // Obviosuly here you can put the condition you need not necessarily "!= null"
  if (request.getMyProperty() != null) {
     return getMyProperty();
  // else the request goes to the linked class
  } else if (successor != null) {
     successor.processRequest(request);
}
```

where now

```
class B extends CommonProperties {
    [....] 
} 
class A extends CommonProperties {    
    private CommonProperties B successors;  
    [....] 
}
```